# Will stopping and starting AWS EC2 and RDS instance through lambda expression at a specific interval lead to cause any problem?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I have one running **RDS(MSSql Server)** and **EC2 instance**. I found some solutions to stop and start instances automatically through the Lambda expression at a specific interval. I want to apply one of these solutions to start and stop RDS(MSSql Server) and EC2 instance. This action makes me worried about that  **Does it affect my EC2 instance data or RDS instance data and volumes?** Will it be good to start and stop these instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to stop EC2 instance and data the will be persistent, stoping instance from lambda is same as stopping instance from AWS console, or aws-cli.

**When you stop a running instance, the following happens:**

- The instance performs a normal shutdown and stops running; its status changes to stopping and then stopped.
- **Any Amazon EBS volumes remain attached to the instance, and their data persists.**
- Any data **stored in the RAM** of the host computer or the instance store volumes of the host computer is gone.
- In most cases, the instance is migrated to a new underlying host computer when it's started.

[Stop_Start-ec2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html)

Where for RDS, stop last for seven days only and the RDS will start automatically after 7 days. for stopping RDS is fine also same applied to RDS.

> You can stop an instance for up to 7 days at a time. After 7 days, it
>   will be automatically started. For more details on stopping and
>   starting a database instance, please refer to Stopping and Starting a
>   DB Instance in the Amazon RDS User Guide.

[USER_StopInstance-RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html)

> Does it affect my EC2 instance data or RDS instance data and volumes?
>   Will it be good to start and stop these instances?

No, only data RAM affected. if you are not using regular then stopping is good to save cost.

Comment: one more **important point** to note down that is when the **EC2 instance** start from stop state the instance public IP will change. So, please don't forget about your IP bindings.